# OpenCV4Windows cant find ostream.h, sstream.h and stdint.h

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I have been working with OpenCV4Android and produced a library to use in my android apps, i want to create the same library to use in any windows software, now using **OpenCV4Windows**.

The problem is that I have been unable to compile the code due to different headers not found ( called by OpenCV) this is specially strange as i am still able to compile the same code for android (using OpenCV4Android)

Already tried different versions of OpenCV4Windows and no success
the following line:

```
g++ -c MMROI.cpp -ID:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include
```

gives this result:

```
"*In file included from D:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/cvdef.h:59,
                 from D:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core.hpp:52,
                 from D:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include\opencv2/opencv.hpp:46,
                 from MMROI.hpp:4,
                 from MMROI.cpp:5:
D:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include\opencv2/hal/defs.h:274: stdint.h: No such file or directory
In file included from D:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core.hpp:3107,
                 from D:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include\opencv2/opencv.hpp:46,
                 from MMROI.hpp:4,
                 from MMROI.cpp:5:
D:\software\OpenCV4Windows\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp:49: ostream: No such file or directory*"
```

Comment: Hmm.... the ".h" way of writing headers has been deprecated (should be `<ostream>`, `<sstream>`, and `<cstdint>`)...

Comment: i checked the base code of opencv and that is how they are written ...with the '<ostream>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, it was a really old version of g++, it was solved by reinstalling cygwin and updating the g++ and gcc packages